# Facebook API - Post photo and link to wall simultaneously

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Is it possible to post image and link together? Here is my code :

```
try {
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);

if(!isset($userLink)){
   $postResult = $facebook->api(
                  '/'.$userGroupId.'/photos/',
                  'post',
                  array(
                     'message' => $userMessage,
                     'source' => '@'.$_FILES["source"]["tmp_name"] ));
}else{
   $postResult = $facebook->api(
                  '/'.$userGroupId.'/photos/',
                  'post',
                  array(
                     'message' => $userMessage,
                     'link' => $userLink,
                     'source' => '@'.$_FILES["source"]["tmp_name"] ));
  }
}
catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log('Could not post image to Facebook.');
}
```

Without `'link'` everything is ok, but if I insert link into array i got an error : `Notice: Undefined variable: postResult in..`

Is there something wrong with my code? Please help, Thank you.

Comment: _“Is it possible to post image and link together?”_ – nope, those are different kinds of posts: You can either post a link, or a photo, but not both simultaneously. Of course you can pack a URL into the `message` parameter when publishing a photo – but please be aware that this parameter has to contain content actively generated by the user, and not just to be pre-filled with a site you want to “advertise”, because that would be considered spam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/), the **link** parameter is-

> A link to the photo on Facebook (that you wish to upload)

But you are using it in another way, to share link along with the photo- which is not possible. For sharing a link on wall you have to use [Feed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) instead.

Comment: `link` is not a parameter for _creating_ a new photo at all – it is just one of the properties you get back from the API when reading the details of an already existing photo.

Comment: @CBRoe No it is, you can try it out. And in fact not just the facebook photos, its posting any photos using `link` - i just tried and it worked :)